# Shifting the index of a sequence to prove convergence.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently studying sequences in Real Analysis and really struggling with answering this basic question:

Prove that if $x_n→a$, then for any fixed positive integer k the sequence $\{y_n\},y_n=x_{n+k}$ also converges to $a$

I honestly have no idea how to even start this proof. Could someone provide me with some hints? Specifically, what does $y_n=x_{n+k}$ represent in terms of sequences? Is this a case of induction?

Comment: Start with the definition of what it means for a sequence to converge.

Comment: Well a sequence converges when its limit tends to some finite number. I really don't know how to expand that definition. It is pretty simply. Where I'm primarily stuck is on trying to understand $y_n=x_{n+k}$. What does that subscript $k$ represent in the sequence?

Comment: Roughly speaking, a sequence converges to a limit if terms past a particular one are within a certain closeness to the limit; the $+k$ merely shifts the indexing of the terms; so, for example, if previously you could say all terms past the $9^{th}$ are within $0.1$ of $L$, after shifting the index by applying $+5$ you could say all terms past the $4^{th}$ are within $0.1$ of $L$

Comment: You misunderstand the intent of @TrevorGunn's comment in two ways: (1) Your math book or your teacher should have given you a very precise mathematical expression (i.e. constraint) with the idea that a sequence converges to a value $L$ if and only if the constraint is satisfied.  What is the precise mathematical expression for this constraint?  You can **not** attack your query without first answering this question.  (2) **All** of your analysis belongs in the query, not in comments.  Please answer question (1) by editing your query.  Then, edit your query again, with an attempt to solve.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So essentially, no matter how we shift the index the limit should still converge to the same point? That is, $\lim_{x\ ->\infty} a_n = \lim_{x\ ->\infty} a_{n+k}  = L$

Comment: That’s right, @Dylan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first thing one could do is to understand intuitively why the desired property is correct. When we have a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to a number $a$, then
for all $n$ big enough, $x_n$ gets really close to $a$. Since for $k\in \mathbb{N}$, sequence $(x_{n+k})=(x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\ldots)$ just ignores the first $k$ terms of $(x_n)$, the behaviour does not change for large enough $n$ and therefore it is reasonable to suspect that it also converges to $a.$

Now, for the proof.

**Heuristic.** We start by stating precisely what we want to prove:

for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_0$, $|x_{n+k}-a|<\varepsilon$.

Since you want to prove something for all $\varepsilon>0$, let ${\color{red}\varepsilon}>0$ (be random, but fixed). Now we are looking for a suitable $n_0$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_0$, $|x_{n+k}-a|<{\color{red}\varepsilon}$. We don't have any other choice than using what we already have:  $\varepsilon>0$ and the fact that $(x_n)$ converges to $a$. Especially, if you use the convergence, you know that for all
${\color{blue}\varepsilon}>0$ there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_0$, $|x_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$. Note that, although we used the same notation,
the ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ at the beginning of our proof is not the same as ${\color{blue}\varepsilon}$ (since the last one comes along with quantifier for all ($\forall$)). Since you know that for all
${\color{blue}\varepsilon}>0$ something interesting happens, an interesting choice would be to use ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ (which is positive).
Indeed, using ${\color{red}\varepsilon}>0$ there is some
$n_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_1$, $|x_{n}-a|<{\color{red}\varepsilon}$.

Ok, now we found (basically, not really found, but proved the existence of a) $n_1$ such that terms  $x_{n}$ get ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ close to $a$ thereafter. Now it all comes to the relation of $n_1$ and $k.$
If $n_1$ is bigger than  $k$, then the terms $x_{n_1},x_{n_1+1},\ldots$ are terms of the sequence $(x_{k+1},x_{x+2},\ldots)$ and of course are ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ close to $a$, so if we choose $n_0:=n_1-k\in \mathbb{N},$ then for $n\geqslant n_0$ one gets $n+k\geqslant n_1$ and so terms
$x_{n+k}$ are ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ close to $a$. On the other hand, if
$n_1\leqslant k$, then for all $n\geqslant 1$ we have $n+k> n_1$ and so terms
$x_{n+k}$ are ${\color{red}\varepsilon}$ close to $a$, so in this case choosing $n_0:=1$ is good enough. Eventually, one could choose: $$n_0:=\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
n_1-k&,~ n_1>k \\
1&, n_1\leqslant  k\\
\end{array}
\right..$$

**Formal presentation.** (*includes all the above, without comments and what instructors often write and let you discover the rest*):
let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(x_n)$ converges to $a$, there exists $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant n_1$ $|x_{n}-a|<\varepsilon$.
If $n_1>k$, then   for $n\geqslant n_1-k$, we   have $|x_{n+k}-a|<\varepsilon$ and
if $n_1\leqslant k$ then for $n\geqslant 1$, we   have $|x_{n+k}-a|<\varepsilon$.

Notes.

1. Choice of $n_0$ is not unique. If you chose $n_0$ to be $n_1+k$, then you are sure that for $n\geqslant n_0$, integer $n$ exceeds $k$ so $x_n$ is term of
   $(x_{n+k})$ and  also integer $n$ exceeds $n_1$ so $x_n$ is $\varepsilon$ close to $a$. It is up to you to choose whatever $n_0$ you prefer (and works of course).
2. The above (hope was not too long) contains all the ideas you need to read and write formal proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_n \to$ a with a $\in \mathbb{R}$. Then by the definition of limit we can write:
$\forall \varepsilon \geq 0(\exists n\in \mathbb {N} (\forall m\in \mathbb {N} (m\geq n\implies |x_{m}-a|<\varepsilon )))$.

Note that given $k \in \mathbb {N}$, n $< n+k$. So it's still true that:

$\forall \varepsilon \geq 0(\exists n\in \mathbb {N} (\forall m\in \mathbb {N} (m\geq n\implies |x_{m+k}-a|<\varepsilon )))$, by the definition of $y_n$ we get:

$\forall \varepsilon \geq 0(\exists n\in \mathbb {N} (\forall m\in \mathbb {N} (m\geq n\implies |y_{m}-a|<\varepsilon )))$. So $y_n$ converges by definition (to a).